# How to make checkboxes disabled when other checkbox is checked?

Tags: events, jsf, listener, checked

help me please! I am novice.
I have 3 components of . If the first selectBooleanCheckbox checked then  the second and third components should be disabled. And if the first selectBooleanCheckbox unchecked then  the second and third components should be active.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox_1" value="#{MyManagerBean.goldRun}"
              valueChangeListener="#{MyManagerBean.valueChangeInput}"/>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox_2" value="#{MymanagerBean.useResult}" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox_3" value="#{MymanagerBean.goldSize}" />
```

How do i do it?

```
 public void valueChangeInput(ValueChangeEvent event) {
       event.getNewValue()......
       .............................
       ..............................
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the kind of behaviour you are looking for can only be accomplished using ajax. If you are using JSF2 then ajax is built into it. You could do something like:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox_1" value="#{MyManagerBean.goldRun}">
  <f:ajax event="change" render="checkBox_2 checkBox_3"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox_2" value="#{MymanagerBean.useResult}" disabled="#{MyManagerBean.goldRun}" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox_3" value="#{MymanagerBean.goldSize}" disabled="#{MyManagerBean.goldRun}"/>
```

The above piece of code would have to be in a form.

If your using JSF 1.2 then you will need to use an ajax supported JSF third party library like [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) / [ICEfaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/). They have similar components that work in the same way.

Comment: It did not help me. I use JSF 2.0. Most importantly, what to write in the listener?

Comment: I think the listener left there from your original code. You can remove it if you don't want it invoked.