# JSF 1.2 checkbox How to get instant response?

Tags: jsf, checkbox, jsf-1.2, icefaces

I have a column of checkboxes and I want to get this effect that when you select 3 of them the rest of checkboxes disables. I've tried everything but I can't make it to do it instantly after clicking on a checkbox (it happens when I reload a page). Every response for that problem is using `<f:ajax>` but I'm using JSF 1.2 (and I can't use JSF 2 in this project). Is there any way to get through my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413973/how-to-make-checkboxes-disabled-when-other-checkbox-is-checked.

Comment: I'm using icefaces but I sadly didn't find anything that could help me

Comment: ICEfaces has ajax capabilities too. By the way, JSF 2.0 was released 2009. Almost a decade ago. Try keeping up with the versions or your webapp will die slowly.

Comment: I don't know why I just didnt use <ace:ajax/>. Just got brainlagged I guess. But despite this I still can't handle my problem. I want to make checkbox's valueChangeListener to work immediatly after click but it seems to not work that way I want to.